# Is there a way to pass an argument to a class constructor when used as a type parameter?

Tags: c#, types, parameters, constructor, arguments

I'm trying to make my code as re-usable as possible, and ran into a problem when trying to pass a constuctor argument to a class used as a type parameter.

What I currently have is this:

```
    public sealed class SubmitForm : DerivedClass
    {            
    }

    public void TestMethod_Simulated()
    {
        var foo = GetObject<SubmitForm>();
        SubmitData(foo);
    }

    private void SubmitData(SubmitForm form)
    {
        // Do work 
    }

    public T GetObject<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        // Work
    }
```

This was working because there was no explicit constructor and parameter for SubmitForm. However I want to extend the functionality and require an explicit constructor expecting an argument.

After adding the constructor, I am looking to call "GetObject" with the type parameter "SubmitForm" INCLUDING an argument for its explicit constructor.

This is clearly not possible in any straightforward way, but I don't want to believe there is not way of getting this to work.

The following shows what I'm trying to achieve, which is to use the class as a type parameter while instantiating it in order to access the constructor I've created:

```
    public sealed class SubmitForm : DerivedClass
    {
        public SubmitForm(EnumType typeVar)
        {
            _derivedVar = typeVar;
        }
    }

    public void TestMethod_Simulated()
    {
        var foo = GetObject<new SubmitForm(EnumType.FormA)>();
        SubmitData(foo);
    }

    private void SubmitData(SubmitForm form)
    {
        // Do work 
    }

    public T GetObject<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        // Work
    }
```

I hope this makes sense. I can't seem to find a way to first instantiate the class AND then use it as a type parameter.

Comment: What is the type of parameter expected by `SubmitData` method?

Comment: Apologies, I've included the signature for the SubmitData method - the type of its parameter is "SubmitForm"

Comment: And you want `GetObject` to create an object of SubmitForm using a specific constructor?

Comment: No, my concern is not with GetObject.. GetObject is existing generic code that constructs a filter object to be used with SubmitData. My issue is that I want to instantiate my SubmitForm class with the correct form type parameter (as per the constructor), so that GetObject can create the correct filter object based on that constructor. The reason for this is because various forms will use the same class, with the exception of a different form type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I hope this makes sense. I can't seem to find a way to first
>   instantiate the class AND then use it as a type parameter

Well, it is not possible to pass an *instance* of a class as generic type parameter. 
A type parameter is just a *placeholder* for type of object. Compiler uses it to infer the type and substitute `T` with a real type. It has nothing to do with actual parameters.

If you want to use a specific instance of `SubmitForm` class in your function you could first create an instance:

```
var submitForm = new SubmitForm(EnumType.FormA);
```

And then change your function to accept an argument of type `T`:

```
public T GetObject<T>(T instance)
    where T : class
{
   // .. do something with instance
}
```

And now you can make a call to the new overload:

```
var someResult = GetObject(submitForm);
```

However from your code sample it's not clear why you  need generic type parameters at all. It seems that you might just as well change the signature of `GetObject` function from `T GetObject<T>()` to `SubmitForm GetObject(SubmitForm form)`

We usually use type parameters when we have a generic function that needs to execute more or less same logics for different types and we don't want to duplicate the same code.

Comment: Thank you Fabjan. I never thought of modifying the GetObject code as its part of a legacy system and I didn't want to mess with it. However to achieve what I wanted to I followed your suggestion, and added the "instance" as an optional paramter of type T, so now I'm instantiating the class and handing that over to the GetObject method. I believe this will work.

The existing code of this system is extremely complex, with a serious inheritence hierarchy and a lot of generics, so I still don't fully understand the reason behind the complexities and architecture the developer implemented.

Comment: @jpsqr You're welcome. A free advice - add as much *useful* information to your question as you can. For example this piece of information that you don't have control over `GetObject` code and it comes from a legacy library is important. Add it to your question and you'll get better and more accurate answer